# How to Loop through a CSV and use each Row String to Create a QR Code - PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, csv, qr-code

I am trying to write a code that will loop through a CSV file I have, combine the two pieces of data ( In this case "Rep" and "Entry") and then create a QR Code for each returned value... I have figured out how to make the QR code and how to Combine the data, but I cannot figure out the loop and how to put all of this together. Thank you for any help!

```
import csv
import qrcode

with open('SLS_labels.csv') as csvfile:
    fieldnames= ["Rep", "Entry"]
    reader= csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        labeldata = row[0] + row[1]
        print labeldata


    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=1,
        border=4,
    )

    qr.add_data(labeldata)
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image()
    img.save("test.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to create you label within the for loop:

```
for row in reader:
    labeldata = row[0] + row[1]

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
    box_size=1,
    border=4)

    qr.add_data(labeldata)
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image()
    img.save(labeldata+".jpg") #this assumes your label data would make a good file name
```

Alternatively you could add all of your `labeldata` to a list and iterate over that...

```
labeldata = []
for row in reader:
    labeldata += [row[0] + row[1]]
...
for label in labeldata:
    #make labels
```

Comment: Why would you want to create a new instance of `qr` for every loop ?

Comment: without reading the documentation I don't know if the `add_data` method is overwriting the old information or concatenating.  If I create a new instance each time I don't have to worry about the possibility of stale data.

Comment: I understand that, but that wouldn't be an ideal way anyway. You should just clear the stale data if need be.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import qrcode

with open('SLS_labels.csv') as csvfile:
    fieldnames= ["Rep", "Entry"]
    reader= csv.reader(csvfile)

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=1,
        border=4,
    )

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        labeldata = row[0] + row[1]
        print labeldata

        qr.add_data(labeldata)
        qr.make(fit=True)

        img = qr.make_image()
        img.save("test{}.jpg".format(i))
```

I added enumerate so you'd also get an index number for your file names instead of having multiple `test.jpg`.

If you want to clear the data added you can call `qr.clear()` after `img.save()`